# Unable to login to Ubuntu 16.04 admin user account

Tags: unity, login, compiz, upstart

Unable to login to Ubuntu 16.04. I had issue of getting only blank desktop screen earlier for which I ran below commands given in other thread to resolve the issue.

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
sudo rm -fr ~/.compiz

sudo rm -fr ~/.Xauthority
sudo rm -fr ~/.config/autostart

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity compizconfig-settings-manager upstart

sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

But the blank desktop issue didn't resolve. I restarted the system in hope that after restart blank issue might go. But now I can't login to my admin account. Always it looped back to login screen asking for password to log. Are all my files gone? How can I login back to my admin account?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have executed `dconf reset` with `sudo` - that's likely resulted in root ownership of files in `~/.config/dconf/`. Log in via a virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F2 for example) and check/fix that if necessary.

Comment: Many thanks steeldriver for the response. I can log via Ctrl-Alt-F2 but since I am novice to get those commands to fix. Can you please help? Any guidance would be appreciated to get back my data or rectify the system. Please help.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.config/dconf/` should do it - you may want to run `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` and `setsid unity` again **without** sudo

Comment: Thanks again mate for the help. All my previous files gone now though had 6 months old back but lost many imp files....can't see anything. Will be careful in future unless 100% sure to run those commands!!

Comment: Those commands shouldn't have resulted in the loss of any files - at least, not unless you miss-typed and wrote `sudo rm -fr ~/`